# sqlite3 in multi-thread mode: what exactly is unsafe to perform?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, sqlite

From the [SQLite documentation article on multithreading](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) I get that in **Multi-thread** mode "*SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads provided that no single database connection is used simultaneously in two or more threads*".

It doesn't explain though: *exactly what* is unsafe to do simultaneously in two or more threads in this mode? Apart from the obvious CREATE, INSERT, UPDATE, DROP etc. queries modifying the database,

1. Is it also unsafe to perform SELECTs simultaneously?

And what about using statements (sqlite3_stmt)? Is it also unsafe to simultaneously use them if they are connected with the same database? Especially:

2. preparing statements (sqlite3_prepare_v2)
3. binding values (sqlite3_bind*)
4. clearing bindings (sqlite3_clear_bindings)
5. resetting statement (sqlite3_reset)
6. opening/closing new connections to the same database in different threads (sqlite3_open_v2, sqlite3_close_v2)

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, *any* operation on the `sqlite3` object from two or more threads at the same time is dangerous in multi-threaded mode. Same applies to `sqlite3_stmt` objects, since they are "part of" the `sqlite3` object.

However, you can (and usually do) have more than one `sqlite3` connection to the same database, even in different processes. SQLite will manage concurrency between them.

Comment: When you have multiple connections to the same database, SQLite won't fully handle concurrency, i.e. you still may crash on `SQLITE_BUSY` error. My question arises exactly because I'd like to know which parts of the code neccessarily _have_ to be isolated with a mutex if multiple threads are to simultaneously insert data to the same database, and which don't. It would save a lot of computation time to reduce mutexes to minimum. I haven't been able to find any comprehensive answer to that in the official resources, though.

Comment: Under multi-threading mode, my understanding is that any access to a `sqlite3` connection must be synchronized, and that accessing sub-objects like `sqlite3_stmt`s counts as accessing the `sqlite3` connection they were created from. Also, `SQLITE_BUSY` is not a crash; you can retry the query or set up a [busy handler](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_handler.html) or [timeout](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html)